# When should you insist on training in a new technology?

Tags: project-management

G'day,

I have been involved in a project that has required my becoming familiar with several new technologies because several tasks were left off the project plan. I just figured that I'd dive and and learn what was needed to get the various jobs done. Generally, this learning was done on my own time.

So far the list of technologies I have had to learn are:

- Solaris 10 SMF and migration from legacy rc directories.
- Solaris 10 svcadm,
- Solaris 10 inetadm and migration from inetd mechanisms, and
- zfs, zpools and zfs snapshots.

Now I have to learn Solaris Cluster because the couple of people who insisted that they had to go on the Solaris Cluster course before they could do anything are too busy to help.

At what point do people insist on being sent on training courses? What approach do you use to get such training and how do you justify it?

BTW I'm extremely lucky that the project manager knows that I have had to learn all of this and is extremely grateful. I think I would've "gone postal" if, in addition to all the extra learning, I had a PM who was perpetually wondering "why is it taking so long?"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your job requires you to do some work in a technology that you are not versed in, and you went into the job with all parties knowing that you didn't know that technology, then it is the responsibility of the employer (IMO) to:

- Provide time for you to learn the material on your own
- Send you on a course to learn the material if necessary
- Acquire resources (i.e. books) for you to reference

If, however, you were expected to know the material beforehand, then it is your responsibility to complete the above three tasks.

Answer (score 1):

So you learned stuff to do employer required work on your own time (unpaid)? And your boss is extremely grateful? Well duh.

My motto is - if my employer requires me to learn some new technology - then send me on a course or budget some time for me to learn it on my own.

Answer (score 1):

I think one case is when the technology is proprietary and there just isn't that much learning material freely available. In order to get your job done, your boss will just have to suck it up and pay for the training (Which is probably overpriced, but would be almost impossible to learn otherwise).